# Validate excel file columns that are non-decimal once imported in the DataGridView?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I am trying to make an Excel Validation program. The program aims to import an .xls file and when imported can detect non-decimal values in columns January to December.

I want to show the non-decimal cells by highlighting them.

Here's the screenshot. [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wETW1.png)

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell = dataGridView1[2, e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewTextBoxCell;

    if (cell != null)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 4)
        {
            char[] chars = e.FormattedValue.ToString().ToCharArray();
            foreach (char c in chars)
            {
                if (char.IsDigit(c) == false)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You have to enter digits only");

                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

I found this code above but it can only show the result when editing and hitting the enter key then shows a messagebox. I want it to be validated once imported by highlighting non decimal cells in a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void Column_Validating(DataGridView dataGridView)
    {
        decimal num;
        if (dataGridView.ColumnCount > 3)
        {
            for (int h = 4; h < dataGridView.ColumnCount; h++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    if (!Decimal.TryParse(dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString(), out num))
                    {
                        if (dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() == null || dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() == "") { }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Row not decimal:" + " [ " + dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() + "] in column "  + dataGridView.Columns[h].Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int h = 3; h < dataGridView.ColumnCount; h++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount; i++)
                {

                    if (!Decimal.TryParse(dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString(), out num))
                    {
                        if (dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() == null || dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() == "") { }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("KEK " + dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Made my own method on a different class.
This validates columns January up to December.